# Finding the number of people in a database and displaying a table with each "students" name as the row title

Tags: python, sql, database

I'm trying to build a program where you can add students to the database then in the main window there is a table where you can add a number into each week on how the student is doing.

So far I have made a screen that can add students into the database now I need a class that will allow me to display a table with 8 columns and x amount of rows.

I'm thinking that I need a function that firstly finds the length of the db file (students), this will give me a X value

Then I need to have another function that will create the table with x rows 
and name each of the rows the students names.

SO FAR....
I've searched the Internet for some code on tables from a database that is editable and nothing..
I decided that I could use tkinter text boxes as seen below:

[image: maths table]

then I can take whatever was inserted into the text boxes and calculate what I need.

Now I don't know how to do the next bit any help will be much appreciated

UPDATE

Been doing some more research and I think that you could use a select NAME function to print off all of the names and then somehow use this as the titles for each row

UPDATE 2

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

class mainwindow:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Maths Tracker")

        self.week1lbl = Label(master,text="WEEK 1")
        self.week2lbl = Label(master,text="WEEK 2")
        self.week3lbl = Label(master,text="WEEK 3")
        self.week4lbl = Label(master,text="WEEK 4")
        self.week5lbl = Label(master,text="WEEK 5")
        self.week6lbl = Label(master,text="WEEK 6")
        self.week7lbl = Label(master,text="WEEK 7")
        self.week8lbl = Label(master,text="WEEK 8")



        self.week1entery = Entry(master)
        self.week2entery = Entry(master)
        self.week3entery = Entry(master)
        self.week4entery = Entry(master)
        self.week5entery = Entry(master)
        self.week6entery = Entry(master)
        self.week7entery = Entry(master)
        self.week8entery = Entry(master)


        self.week1lbl.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.week1entery.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W)

        self.week2lbl.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=W)
        self.week2entery.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky=W)

        self.week3lbl.grid(row=3, column=3, sticky=W)
        self.week3entery.grid(row=4, column=3, sticky=W)

        self.week4lbl.grid(row=3, column=4, sticky=W)
        self.week4entery.grid(row=4, column=4, sticky=W)

        self.week5lbl.grid(row=3, column=5, sticky=W)
        self.week5entery.grid(row=4, column=5, sticky=W)

        self.week6lbl.grid(row=3, column=6, sticky=W)
        self.week6entery.grid(row=4, column=6, sticky=W)

        self.week7lbl.grid(row=3, column=7, sticky=W)
        self.week7entery.grid(row=4, column=7, sticky=W)

        self.week8lbl.grid(row=3, column=8, sticky=W)
        self.week8entery.grid(row=4, column=8, sticky=W)


        with sqlite3.connect("students.db") as db:
            c = db.cursor()
            c.execute("SELECT name FROM students") #name being a field and students being the table
            results = c.fetchall() #stores query results in variable called results
            db.commit()
            db.close()
            labelWidgets = []
        for i in range(0, len(results)):
            labelWidgets.append(Label(self, text = results[i]))
            labelWidgets[-1].grid(row= i+1, column =0, sticky='w')


root = Tk()
my_gui = mainwindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

||||||||||||**UPDATE 3** |||||||||||

here is my updated code for mainscreen.py

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3  
import studentdb




class rundb:
    def set_up():
        with sqlite3.connect("students.db") as db:
            cursor = db.cursor()

        cursor.execute('''

        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS students(


        cardnumber INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        firstname VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
        surname VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
        currentgrade VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
        targetgrade VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL);

        ''')


        query = ('select * FROM students')
        cursor.execute(query)


class mainwindow:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Maths Tracker")

        self.week1lbl = Label(master,text="WEEK 1")
        self.week2lbl = Label(master,text="WEEK 2")
        self.week3lbl = Label(master,text="WEEK 3")
        self.week4lbl = Label(master,text="WEEK 4")
        self.week5lbl = Label(master,text="WEEK 5")
        self.week6lbl = Label(master,text="WEEK 6")
        self.week7lbl = Label(master,text="WEEK 7")
        self.week8lbl = Label(master,text="WEEK 8")



        self.week1entery = Entry(master)
        self.week2entery = Entry(master)
        self.week3entery = Entry(master)
        self.week4entery = Entry(master)
        self.week5entery = Entry(master)
        self.week6entery = Entry(master)
        self.week7entery = Entry(master)
        self.week8entery = Entry(master)


        self.week1lbl.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.week1entery.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W)

        self.week2lbl.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=W)
        self.week2entery.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky=W)

        self.week3lbl.grid(row=3, column=3, sticky=W)
        self.week3entery.grid(row=4, column=3, sticky=W)

        self.week4lbl.grid(row=3, column=4, sticky=W)
        self.week4entery.grid(row=4, column=4, sticky=W)

        self.week5lbl.grid(row=3, column=5, sticky=W)
        self.week5entery.grid(row=4, column=5, sticky=W)

        self.week6lbl.grid(row=3, column=6, sticky=W)
        self.week6entery.grid(row=4, column=6, sticky=W)

        self.week7lbl.grid(row=3, column=7, sticky=W)
        self.week7entery.grid(row=4, column=7, sticky=W)

        self.week8lbl.grid(row=3, column=8, sticky=W)
        self.week8entery.grid(row=4, column=8, sticky=W)


        with sqlite3.connect("students.db") as db:
            c = db.cursor()
            c.execute("SELECT cardnumber FROM students") #name being a field and students being the table
            results = c.fetchall() #stores query results in variable called results
            db.commit()
            db.close()
            labelWidgets = []
        for i in range(0, len(results)):
            labelWidgets.append(Label(self, text = results[i]))
            labelWidgets[-1].grid(row= i+1, column =0, sticky='w')


root = Tk()
my_gui = mainwindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

HERE IS MY CODE FOR THE DATABASE (studentdb.py)

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3
class databasewindow:

def __init__(self,master):
    self.master = master
    master.title("Students")

    self.cardnumberlbl = Label(master,text="Card Number:- ")
    self.forenamelbl = Label(master,text="Forename: - ")
    self.surnamelbl = Label(master,text="Surname: - ")
    self.currentgradelbl = Label(master,text="Current Grade: -")
    self.targetgradelbl = Label(master,text="Target Grade: -")


    self.cardnumberentry = Entry(master)
    self.forenameentry = Entry(master)
    self.surnameentry = Entry(master)
    self.currentgradeentry = Entry(master)
    self.targetgradeentry = Entry(master)




    self.cardnumberlbl.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
    self.cardnumberentry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W+E)

    self.forenamelbl.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
    self.forenameentry.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W+E)

    self.surnamelbl.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
    self.surnameentry.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W+E)

    self.currentgradelbl.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)
    self.currentgradeentry.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W+E)

    self.targetgradelbl.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=W)
    self.targetgradeentry.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=W+E)



    self.submit_button = Button(master, text="add record", command=self.addrecord)
    self.submit_button.grid(row=9,column=0,sticky=W+E)




def addrecord(self):

    with sqlite3.connect("student.db") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cardnumber = self.cardnumber.get()
        firstname = self.firstname.get()
        surname = self.surname.get()
        currentgrade = self.currentgrade.get()
        targetgrade = self.targetgrade.get()


    query = ('INSERT INTO customers(cardnumber, firstname, surname,currentgrade, targetgrade) VALUES' )
    fields = ("("'+ cardnumber +'","' + firstname +'","'+ surname +'","'+ currentgrade'","'+ targetgrade'");")


    cursor.execute(query + fields)

    db.commit()

    query = (' SELECT * FROM students')
    cursor.execute(query)
```

I'm now getting an error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\student.brookeweston.org\31306$\CS course work\databse\mainscreen.py", line 92, in <module>
    my_gui = mainwindow(root)
  File "\\student.brookeweston.org\31306$\CS course work\databse\mainscreen.py", line 81, in __init__
    c.execute("SELECT cardnumber FROM students") #name being a field and students being the table
**sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: students**
```

Answer (score 1):

obviously i dont know how  your database or gui is setup as you have not provided any code but i get the gist of what you are trying to do and so you could try something like this:

Step 1 connect to your database:

```
with sqlite3.connect("students.db") as db: 
     c = db.cursor()
     c.execute("SELECT name FROM students") #name being a field and students being the table
     results = c.fetchall() #stores query results in variable called results
     db.commit()
     db.close()
```

Step 2 - loop through results and add to label text

```
labelWidgets = []
for i in range(0, len(results)):
            labelWidgets.append(Label(self, text = results[i]))
            labelWidgets[-1].grid(row= i+1, column =0, sticky='w')
```

So this will create x number of widgets where x is the number of students in your database and label them with the students name.

Note - you can modify the grid configurations to how you want to display them. Furthermore you can add entry widgets in the same for loop for each student.

Comment: Hi, thank you I have added my code into the question.